# Inspect local image with Skopeo

Tags: docker, docker-registry, skopeo

I am able to inspect remote images using Skopeo

```
skopeo inspect docker://{registry}/{repository}:latest
```

but I cannot figure out how to run the same on a local image (same as I would do with `docker inspect`).
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **docker-daemon** repository type:

```
skopeo inspect docker-daemon:myimage:0.0.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try skopeo inspect containers-storage:<repository/image name> for example:

```
skopeo inspect containers-storage:localhost/myimg
```

Comment: I finally managed to try your suggestion, thanks for taking the time. I do however get an error:
`FATA[0000] Error parsing image name "containers-storage:repo/image:v1": chown /Users/userxxx/.local/share/containers/storage/vfs: operation not permitted`